# Convert csv in php and get unique value

Tags: php, csv

I would like to convert a csv file that has duplicate contents and i would like to sum the quantity and extract the price without sum it.

file.csv :

```
code,qty,price
001,2,199
001,1,199
002,2,159
002,2,159
```

Actual php that sum the quantiy and get a result with unique value and total qty.

```
<?php
$tsvFile = new SplFileObject('file.csv');
$tsvFile->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$tsvFile->setCsvControl("\t");
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$header = array('sku', 'qty');
fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');

foreach ($tsvFile as $line => $row) {
    if ($line > 0) {
        if (isset($newData[$row[0]])) {
            $newData[$row[0]]+= $row[1];
        } else {
            $newData[$row[0]] = $row[1];
            }
}
}
foreach ($newData as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($file, array($key, $value), ',', '"');
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

the result for this is:

```
code,qty
001,3
002,4
```

and i would like to add price, but without sum it.

The result i need is:

```
code,qty,price
001,3,199
002,4,159
```

Comment: what do you mean by "without sum it" , what do you want as out put, give some example

Comment: edited and added the example of needs

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this yet, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$tsvFile = new SplFileObject('file.csv');
$tsvFile->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$tsvFile->setCsvControl("\t");
$file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$header = array('sku', 'qty');
fputcsv($file, $header, ',', '"');

foreach ($tsvFile as $line => $row) {
    if ($line > 0) {
        if(!isset($newData[$row[0]])) {
            $newData[$row[0]] = array('qty'=>0, 'price'=>$row[2]);
        }
        $newData[$row[0]]['qty'] += $row[1];
    }
}
foreach ($newData as $key => $arr) {
    fputcsv($file, array($key, $arr['qty'], $arr['price']), ',', '"');
}
fclose($file);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there's a nice function on the PHP page [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) which will help you end up with a more legible array to work with:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',') {
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        return FALSE;

    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if(!$header)
                $header = $row;
            else
                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is purely for legibility sake but now comes the code which would allow you to work over the array.

```
$aryInput = csv_to_array('file.csv', ',');
$aryTemp = array();
foreach($aryInput as $aryRow) {
    if(isset($aryTemp[$aryRow['code'])) {
        $aryTemp[$aryRow['code']['qty'] += $aryRow['qty'];
    } else {
        $aryTemp[$aryRow['code']] = $aryRow;
    }
}
```

In the above code, it simply:

Loops through the input
Checks whether the key exists in a temporary array
If it does, it just adds the new quantity
If it doesn't, it adds the entire row

Now you can write out your expectant csv file :)

Comment: this is the same thing i have writed in the question, what i need is to inject the price to. Thx

Comment: This does inject the price. It uses the original table, runs through and if it finds a duplicate "code" just adds the qty columns together leaving the rest of the entry intact. Have you tried it out?